Is Death Penalty allowed for Punishing lgbtq sex?
I read this Sutra in the Baudhayana Dharmasutra:
A man who ejaculates his semen in any place other than the vagina becomes equal to a thief, equal to a murderer of a foetus.
——————————————————————————
And here’s some Shlokas and Sutras that I read about Murdering a foetus:
From Mahabharata Shanti Parva:
https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a164.htm
One guilty of foeticide becomes cleansed if he dies of wounds received in battle fought for the sake of kine and Brahmanas. He may also be cleansed by casting his person on a blazing fire.
Parashar Smriti Sutra 20:
What sin is incurred in killing a Brahman, abortion causes a sin twice as great ; there is no atonement for that sin. The abandonment of such a woman has been ordained by law.
Yajnyavalkya Smriti Sutra 49:
If a woman subjects herself to abortion, except in the case of adultery and for purposes of expiation, she becomes guilty of two great sins the murder of the foetus and the murder of her husband(Yajnavalkya).
Mahabharata Udyoga Parva:
One that setteth fire to a dwelling house, an administerer of poison, a pander, a vendor of the Soma-juice, a maker of arrows, an astrologer, one that injureth friends, an adulterer, one that causeth abortion, a violater of his preceptor's bed, a Brahmana addicted to drink, one that is sharp-speeched, a raker of old sores, an atheist, a reviler of the Vedas, and taker of bribes, one whose investiture with the sacred thread has been delayed beyond the prescribed age, one that secretly slayeth cattle, and one that slayeth him who prayeth for protection,--these all are reckoned as equal in moral turpitude as the slayers of Brahmanas
Mahanirvana Tantra 11:69, 11:70
The woman who causes a miscarriage before the completion of the fifth month, as well as the person who helps her thereto, should be heavily punished by the king (69).
The woman who after the fifth month destroys the child in her womb, and the person who helps her thereto, are guilty of murder (70).
—————————————————————————
Does this mean the Death Penalty can also be used for Punishing lgbtq sex or no?

Related : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/55691/22857 Besides, no record exists of any Hindu authority ever prescribing death penalty for non-vaginal sex.

And the term अयोनौ रेतः सिञ्चति does not necessarily means homosexuality only, it also covers anal sex, oral sex, masturbation & bestiality as well. So do you want to say these activities (which Manu classifies to be below upapatakas) are also punishable by death ?

@অনু well yes besides the Baudhayana Dharmasutra I can’t think any other Shastras which say outside vagina is equal to Mahapatakas and yea I agree that outside vagina also includes even masturbation too (also bad bcuz killing sperm) but according to Baudhayana Dharmasutra I’m guessing its still punished by Death (because equal to Abortion) and I read a lot other Harsh Punishments in the Shastras but it’s Kali Yuga now and I think in past Yugas they were probably forced for everyone but now in Kali Yuga it’s normal to do Paap now and I read that Bhakti and Charity can free you of bigger Paap

(That’s just my understanding from right now)

If a man commits sexual intercourse with a man then he should bath with his clothes as per manusmriti, so no death penalty

मैथुनं तु समासेव्य पुंसि योषिति वा द्विजः । गोयानेऽप्सु दिवा चैव
सवासाः स्नानमाचरेत् ॥ १७४ ॥
If a twice-born man commits an unnatural offence with a male, or has
intercourse with a female in an ox-cart, or in water, or during the
day,—he should take a bath along with his clothes.—(X.174)

Man having intercourse with a man leads to loss of caste, so he may perform penances to regain his caste

ब्राह्मणस्य रुजः कृत्वा घ्रातिरघ्रेयमद्ययोः । जैह्म्यं च मैथुनं पुंसि
जातिभ्रंशकरं स्मृतम् ॥ ६७ ॥
Causing pain to a Brāhmaṇa,—smelling at things that should not be
smelt, or at wine,—cheating—and sexual intercourse with a man,—all
this is declared to lead to loss of caste.—(11.66)

Edit: Baudhyana Dharmasutra on forbidden intercourse

He who has had forbidden intercourse, or has committed a crime against
nature, becomes even like a thief, even like the slayer of a learned
Brāhmaṇa III.7.2

It doesn't say equal to the murderer of foetus but equal to murder of a learned Brahmin.

This is correct information but what about Baudhayana Dharmasutra 3.7.2 which says that outside vagina is the same as Abortion which the Punishment is Death? What’s your Opinion?

@MahadevJiDaBhagat please recheck I edited the answer

that’s actually a mistranslation its actually Murderer of a Foetus but both are very big Paap but would you agree that this is a Valid Punishment for forbidden intercourse and masturbation or what is your opinion?

@MahadevJiDaBhagat The word भ्रूणहन् indeed means killer of learned only, भ्रूणहन्तृ means killing a foetus please check here learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=bhrUNahan&dir=se

Sorry I didn’t reply back to this until now I just saw it today but Brahmahatya is 1 of the Mahapatakas and it’s just as bad if not wayy worse so it’s also Punished by Death according to Manusmriti 9.232, 9.236, and 9.242 so am I correct in saying non-vaginal sex can also be punished by Death?

What does रुजः mean?

So after some thinking & doing my own Research I found the answer to this question which is that different Dharmashastras say different things & some Shastras say it’s the same as a Mahapataka like Brahmahatya & some say its a Upapataka
Baudhayana Dharmasutra Praśna III, Adhyāya 7

2, 'He who has had forbidden intercourse, or has committed a crime
against nature, becomes even like a thief, even like the slayer of a
learned Brāhmaṇa.'

Apastamba Dharmasutra 1.19.15

A man who ejaculates his semen in any place other than the vagina
becomes equal to a thief, equal to a murderer of a Brahmin.

Baudhayana Dharmasutra & Apastamba Dharmasutra say it’s a Mahapataka & it’s the same as killing a Brahmin which means a Brahmin should be banished but Non-Brahmins are Punished by Death
Manusmriti 9.232

Forgers of royal proclamations, sowers of disaffection among the
people, the slayers of women, infants and Brāhmaṇas, and those serving
his enemies,—the king shall put to death.—(232)

But Manusmriti says it’s a Upapataka and it’s Punished for Dwija Men by bathing but it’s Punished for women & Shudras by having 2 fingers cut off or have the hair shaved off & ride on a donkey
Manusmriti 11.174

If a twice-born man commits an unnatural offence with a male, or has
intercourse with a female, in an ox-cart, or in water, or during the
day, — he should take a bath along with his clothes. — (174)

Manusmriti 8.370

But if a woman pollutes a maiden, she deserves immediate shaving off,
or the amputation of two fingers, and also being carried by a
donkey.—(370)

The Arthashastra says they should be taxed
Arthashastra:

When a man has connection with a woman against the order of nature
(a-yonau), he shall be punished with the first amercement. A man
having sexual intercourse with another man shall also pay the first
amercement.

